BLDC six step commutation table confusion
What is the reason why there are many different six step commutation tables on the internet?
No1 table
No2 table

Table reference: "https://lucidar.me/en/actuators/commutation-for-bldc-motors/"

Table reference "https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/State-Space-Based-Simulink-Modeling-of-BLDC-Motor-Singh-Kulkarni/8d102d1f3f52eefce7c751abbabda063c43e9f82"

MSB - Hi, Where did those images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. a book), there is more detail in that site rule. Always reference to the best of your ability. TY (Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules.)

Why do you think they are different?  For each Hall state, two FETs must be turned on.  One high side and one low side.  Just because Switches on one are Q1 to Q6 and the Q1L&H to Q3L&H, does not make them different in operation.  Just different in wiring.  Site the sources where you got said images and I believe someone will show you they are the same.

There is no difference between the two. There is difference in the way the states are represented. Please refer to a standard technical manual. I have provided link for one of the BLDC controller for further understanding. PIC Family Microcontroller for BLDC
